# Node.js expressjs Nested Routes ,

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-router

index.js

```
const AuthRouter = require("./Routes/Auth/signup")

app.use("/account", AuthRouter)
```

signup.js

```
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
          res.send("Signup")
})
```

This Code works...

But I won't like this, It's Possible in Express.js

index.js

```
const AuthRouter = require("./Routes/Auth/urls")

app.use("/account", AuthRouter)
```

urls.js

```
app.use("/signup", signup)
app.use("/login", login)
```

signup.js

```
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
          res.send("Signup")
})
```

login.js

```
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
          res.send("Login")
})
```

Comment: your examples are not omplete, and please, just show us what is the relevant files that the errors occurs, and include the import and creaton of the variables you use..

Answer (score 1):

You could do it inline as well. I prefer it that way. like this on the server:

```js
app.use('/users', require('../utils/api/user'))
```

And the route file like this called user.js in the given directory:

```js
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    res.render('user', {title: 'User', user})
})
router.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
  res.render('user', {title: 'User', user})
}

module.exports = router
```

Now the route on client side to login is /users/login and to signup is /users/signup

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that.
For instance, you will have to dedicate a specific file for your routes. Say `routes.js` like this:

```
import express from "express";
import { Signup } from "./";

const router = express.Router();

router.post("/signup", signup);

export { router }
```

Also, you have to have something like this in your `server.js` file:

```
import { router as usersRoutes } from "./api/routes/routes";
app.use("/api", usersRoutes);
```

Now, you can send HTTP POST requests to `localhost:3000/api/signup`